# CKeditor save filename not dirname

Tags: php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I am trying to save an image with `ckeditor`, using `kcfinder`. But I want to save only the filename on save. Not `src='/dir/dir/file.jpg'` but `src='file.jpg'`.
I do not know where to start looking for such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [substr](http://php.net/substr)? So `$filename = substr($src, strrpos($src, '/'));`

Comment: That won't change a thing if I understand your question correctly - with strrpos() it will only save the filename.

Comment: Well, if there are multiple occurences i think it is going to go for the last it finds.

Comment: It will start from the last '/' it finds.